# Как по-русски написать словосочетание "«native» приложения на С++"?

Tags: терминология, c++

Как по-русски написать словосочетание "«native» приложения на С++"?

Comment: Скорее всего, для какой-нибудь курсовой. 

Если Вы для книги, пожалуйста, не переводите. Особенно раздражает когда переводят названия классов (Activity, Intent, Service и т.д., например, в книгах про Android).

Comment: Перевести что-ли надо? Тогда предложение давай. Надо задействовать интуицию, вкус и знание русского языка

Comment: Туземные приложения?

Comment: Названия классов переводить конечно не надо. Но когда читаешь в русских книжках "инвестигировать", "продебагить", то это плохо. Хотя "задостав" вместо "клизмы" тоже смешно звучит. Поэтому и говорю - вкус и интуиция! И конкретный случай. Не всегда надо искать взаимо-однозначные соответсвия английских и русских слов, иногда можно и предложение просто по другому построить.

Comment: В зависимости от ситуации. А так "native" - это что-то типа "простой", "естественный"

Comment: пиши "нативный" часто встречается. все понимают

Answer (score 1):

Так и напишите — нативный. Это вполне по-русски: вы легко [найдете это слово в орфографическом словаре](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&word=%ED%E0%F2%E8%E2%ED%FB%E9).

Цитата из словаря русских синонимов:

> Нативный — врожденный, природный, естественный, прирожденный

А вот цитата из толкового словаря БСЭ издания 1997 года:

> Нативный (от лат. nativus — врожденный), в биологии - находящийся в природном состоянии, не модифицированный, сохранивший структуру, присущую ему в живой клетке (напр., нативный белок).

Comment: native используют часто в резюме для определении языка(native english - значит что родной язык человека - английский)

Comment: Я часто говорю просто "родной", но в статье (документации) это может выглядеть неуместно. 

Вообще-то (IMHO) native C++ applications  вне контекста (обычно это должно быть противопоставление) выглядит непривычно, в отличие от, например, native code или native methods.